# Reading multiple files from S3 bucket and processing them using Lambda trigger

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

I am reading multiple files in S3, processing them and then making tables in AWS RDS with these processed dataframes. I am doing all this on my Mac OS using PyCharm.

I want to read these csv files from the S3 bucket and run this same python script to process these files in AWS and not on my local system. I want to use lambda to trigger this script and it should run only when all the needed files are uploaded in the bucket.

How would the code vary in AWS Lambda ?

My present code is as below -

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys

client = boto3.client('s3')
resource = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = resource.Bucket('test-s3')



#CREATE ALL THE NEEDED OBJECTS
obj1 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file1.csv')
obj2 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file2.csv')
obj3 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file3.csv')
obj4 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file4.csv')
obj5 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file5.csv')
obj6 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file6.csv')
obj7 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file7.csv')
obj8 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file8.csv')
obj9 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file9.csv')
obj10 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file10.csv')
obj11 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file11.csv')
obj12 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file12.csv')
obj13 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file13.csv')
obj14 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file14.csv')
obj15 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file15.csv')


#CREATE ALL THE DATAFRAMES FROM RESPECTIVE OBJECTS
df_file1 = pd.read_csv(obj1['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file2 = pd.read_csv(obj2['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file3 = pd.read_csv(obj3['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file4 = pd.read_csv(obj4['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file5 = pd.read_csv(obj5['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file6 = pd.read_csv(obj6['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file7 = pd.read_csv(obj7['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file8 = pd.read_csv(obj8['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file9 = pd.read_csv(obj9['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file10 = pd.read_csv(obj10['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file11 = pd.read_csv(obj11['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file12 = pd.read_csv(obj12['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file13 = pd.read_csv(obj13['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file14 = pd.read_csv(obj14['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
df_file15 = pd.read_csv(obj15['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')


#+++++++++++ make a function to process the data frames ++++++++++++


def function(df_file1, df_file2):
     *** some logic ***

        return df_final



## MAKE THE TABLES IN RDS

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2
engine = create_engine('postgresql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@***.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/DBNAME')
df_final.to_sql('table name', engine, schema='data')
```

I am a noob at AWS Lambda. How do I run this script on Lambda?

After taking Ninad's suggestion I edited the script. It's as below-

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys

client = boto3.client('s3')
resource = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = resource.Bucket('test-s3')

def function(df_file1, df_file2):
     *** some logic ***

        return df_final



def lambda_handler(event, context):
    obj1 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file1.csv')
    obj2 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file2.csv')
    obj3 = client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key='file3.csv')


    df_file1 = pd.read_csv(obj1['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep=',')
    df_file2 = pd.read_csv(obj2['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep=',')
    df_file3 = pd.read_csv(obj3['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep=',')


    df_final = function(df_file1, df_file2)

    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    import psycopg2
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@***.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/DBNAME')
    df_final.to_sql('table name', engine, schema='data')
```

I made a virtual environment in my local system and installed all the packages - pandas, SQLAlchemy etc. I zipped this package and the script and uploaded it to Lambda. Now I am getting this error -

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pandas'
```

I have followed [aws package deploy link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) to package all necessary stuff. Why Do I still get an error then ?

Comment: would you like to trigger lamda as soon as a csv file is uploaded? Or are you looking to process all csv files that are currently present on your s3?

Comment: @NinadGaikwad - I would like to trigger the lambda once all the files are uploaded. If that cannot be done then I would like to process all files that are present on S3.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad - I want to know how the code will be deployed and what will be the changes in the script?

Comment: Why not simply run lambda for every csv upload? How will AWS know that you are done uploading all files? Processing a single file as it is uploaded is more suitable for lambda due to its time restrictions.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad - Because I am making functions that need multiple files. Is there a way that it can just process all the files in the bucket in S3 ? Maybe I can schedule the lambda job after the files are done uploading. I am a noob. hence looking for suggestions.

Comment: Yes it can be done. Lamda timeout is a maximum of 15 minutes. If your script will be done executing by that time I will list a full answer to how you can do this.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad The files will be done uploading in 5-7 minutes. The script may take longer. In that case will lambda shutdown the processing? If yes what is the alternative?

Comment: Lambda will be terminated after 15 minutes regardless of whether the task is complete. You will get a timeout error after that.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad - The file upload takes 5-7 minutes. If the processing happens after the upload has been done then it will finish within 10 mins. If I add the time of file upload and script processing then it will take 15-17 mins. If I do not use lambda as trigger but merely as a way to run this script on a bunch of files will it work?

Comment: If the script takes 10 minutes max then it should work. I will list down the main steps you can follow

Comment: @NinadGaikwad - Hey Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the console to create a lambda. Select the correct python version you want and also ensure you have alloted enough memory and put the timeout time to 15 minutes (maximum). When creating the lambda it will also let you attach a role to it. Create a role and attach a policy to the role that lets you access the the s3 bucket where your CSVs will be.

Next step is to create a layer for your lambda which will have all the dependencies that you need for your script to run. Lambda by default has boto3 package installed but you will need to install pandas (with all its dependencies), sqlalchemy and psycopg2. You can find a simple tutorial on how to do this [here](https://blog.skbali.com/2018/11/aws-lambda-layer-example-in-python/)

Now that you have created a layer, attach that layer to your lambda.

We can finally move on to your script. Since you need to read all csv files on your s3 path, you will have to change your script to read the csv files dynamically. Currently you have hardcoded the names of the csv files. You can change your script to first get all the keys in your bucket using something like:

```
response = client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket=my_bucket
)['Contents']
```

This will give you a list of your keys. Filter them if you need.

Next you can create multiple dataframes by looping through the response like this:

```
d = {}
for idx, obj in enumerate(response):
    d['df_'+idx] = pd.read_csv(client.get_object(Bucket='test-s3', Key=obj['Key'])['Body'], encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
```

This will create a dictionary d with all your dataframes. Please try this code out locally first to correct any mistakes.

Now copy your final code and paste it in the lambda editor above the `def lambda handler():` Call your function from within the lambda handler function.

Comment: You can certainly hardcode the names. I assumed that you might not know beforehand what the names of the csv files will be. If you do know, then feel free to hardcode them.

Comment: Hey Thanks! How will I access the dataframes from within the dictionary d ? The response and the dictionary d definition will be under the def lambda handler()?

Comment: Thanks! I will try that out :)

Comment: You can ignore the dictionary d part if you're planning on hardcoding the names of your csv. Just keep your code as is and paste it on top of lambda handler function.

Comment: Hey Thanks for clarifying that. But what should be kept under the lambda handler function() ? If I place my script on top of it.

Comment: Think of the lambda handler as your `if __name__ == 'main':` This is where the compiler looks first. You can call your functions from within this.

Comment: Hey ! I tried to change the script according to your suggestion. I also created a virtual environment and installed all packages, zipped and uploaded it to lambda. Now I get an error no module named pandas. Why is that ?

Comment: I'm guessing you are on windows. Lambda runs on linux and needs the linux version of libraries. https://medium.com/@korniichuk/lambda-with-pandas-fd81aa2ff25e

Comment: Instead of packaging with the lambda handler like it says in the article you can simply put it in the zip you create for layer. That will be much more convenient

Comment: I am on Mac OS. I haven't created a layer. I just zipped the packages from the virtual environment with the script file and uploaded it using AWS CLI because the zipped file is more than 40 mb in size. Do I need to create layer if I upload a zipped package?

Comment: It isn't mandatory but it is good practice. It lets you keep your code light and allows you to use inline code editor in the console to make small changes to your lambda.

Comment: Any suggestion why I get this error? The zipped file has pandas , SQLAlchemy and the rest. Still it can't find pandas.

Comment: Your folder structure might be off, the library you uploaded might be incompatible with the environment on lambda. It will be best if you follow the steps in that medium article i posted. It will install the correct libraries that are compatible.